# Shared Library is outputting into stdout

Tags: c++, apache, shared-libraries, cgi-bin

I'm writting an application in C++ that must use the stdout to output responses (it is a CGI-BIN daemon called from Apache web server, and the Apache gets the stdout of the binary as a response).

The big problem is that I'm using a Shared Library and it outputs logs into the stdout as well, those logs go straight to the http client making it unable to parse the actual HTTP responses.

My question is, is there any way I can suppress those outputs coming from the shared library?

PS: I'm running it on Linux and using *.so libraries

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would have to rebuild the library with whatever options (or code hackery) are necessary to suppress them. That said, do you know for certain that the library is outputting to stdout and not stderr?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the library is outputting, it even prints its name on logs. Well, It's a third party library, it is not possible to rebuild it.

Comment: If for some reason @JesperJuhl's answer doesn't help, another option might be to split your CGI binary into an Apache-facing side which does not use this .so, and a secondary executable that does; that secondary executable would get spawned with a different stdout, and have a private comm channel to the primary one (which then just acts as a relay). Pretty ugly... uglier than tracking down the 3rd party and making them fix their broken library :-)

Comment: What kind of library is this? Maybe there is a replacement with better behavior?

Answer (score 0):

1) that's a bad library. Libraries shouldn't write to stdout.

2) you can maybe get around it by duplicating the stdout file descriptor on the stderr descriptor and then closing stdout.    Feels like a nasty hack though.

Comment: Yep, it's not the best library. Can you post a solution code for that?

Comment: @Diego Tsutsumi : you can easily research that yourself. Hints `dup(2)` and `close()`.

Comment: Thanks for the hints :) . There's another problem, the library outputs 3 lines of log before my main function is called by the system. Something like "Library loaded successfully", in that case your solution wouldn't work, because I'd be calling the dup(2) and close() later on.

Comment: You may be able to force instantiation of class that cuts off the library's access to stdout in the class's constructor ahead of the library. Is this a shared library (.so, .dll)? If so you should be able to dynamically load it on your own terms.

Comment: @user4581301: Thanks for the comment, I will try to load the library after the startup of my application and see what happens. :)

Comment: @user4581301: For some reason when I loaded the shared library in my code using dlopen(3), it didn't output. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Love to, but I can't do that. I don't know why it didn't output, and that makes for a weak answer... Unless you left @JesperJuhl 's hint about `dup` and `close` in place. In that case, then yeah, If you loaded the DLL after cutting off its access to stdout that would be the expected behaviour and Jesper deserves the credit.

Comment: @user4581301: I don't know either (what makes me uncertain of the quality of the solution), anyway thanks, I found a solution seeking after your advice.